# Proportional Poisson Process Problem

Tags: poisson-distribution, proportion, poisson-process

The alliteration is unintentional, but I was amused so I'll leave the title as is.

Anyways, I am looking at a problem where we are trying to predict/justify an observed instantaneous rate by which users on a website will use a particular feature. The data that we are given is that about $A$% of users that log in within a $B$ day period will use the feature at some point, but we are trying to determine a proportion that reflects instantaneously how many users are using the feature at average. We have observed this value to be around $C$% in practice and relatively constant, but need a statistical justification/explanation of this observed value.

I believe that we can model this scenario using a Poisson distribution, but there are a few trouble spots:

1. Overall traffic is not constant which will either involve a simplifying assumption of a constant rate $\lambda$ or a complicated calculation around an inhomogeneous poisson process, which may be overkill for this demonstrative purpose
2. This $A$% value we are given I believe would require the use of the inverse cumulative poisson distribution function, with a very large observed count $k$ in
   $P(x<k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}{\frac{\lambda^{i}e^{-\lambda}}{i!}}$
3. There exists overlap of customers using the feature multiple times in a given window, which implies that I need to account for how much overlap there is and I may be missing an important piece of data that would allow a complete solve of this problem

Is there some change to this approach I should be considering? Keep in mind that we are able to observe this data and can glean other statistics from them, but it is unclear which statistics may be of use. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: bumping thread, still an issue we are investigating